# Update UserIdentities with roles after Azure AD B2C login

Tags: asp.net, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I have a Blazor WASM application communicating with a ASP.NET 6 Web API.

User authentication is done via Azure AD B2C by attaching the AD token to Http requests sent to the Server using

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("Portal.ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7001/api/"))
                .AddHttpMessageHandler<SslAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
```

User specific information like UserRoles is stored in a user database.

I'm using the `RemoteAuthenticatorView.OnLoginSuceeded` handler to load the user profile containing the roles from the API server.

Then I add a new identity to the existing ClaimsPrincipal which I get from the AuthenticationStateProvider like so:

```
var state = await authStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
var user = state.User;

if (user.Identities.Any(x => x.Label == "myAuthToken"))
{
    return;
}

// Turn the JWT token into a ClaimsPrincipal
var principal = tokenService.GetClaimsPrincipal(sslToken);
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(principal.Identity);
identity.Label = "myAuthToken";
user.AddIdentity(identity);
```

Not sure if that's the right way to do this but it works fine.

**Now my problem:**

When I refresh the page by hitting F5 in the browser the above handler is not called and the roles are not written to the new identity, means `user.IsInRole("myRole")` doesn't work.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve the issue of enriching an existing user identity on Blazor with roles coming from the server?

Any help is much appreciated.